# Protect model with validation in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, validation, sanitization, laravel-8

I have database table `phones` with field `phone_number`. I have a model Phone. I want to save Phones in fixed format (sanitized) and with filled `phone_number` (validated)

There are many places in the code where me or my colleagues will need to save phones. I don't believe, that they all will bother to check whether the `phone_number` is filled and in correct format. And I don't want to count on frontend JS validation, or database `NOT NULL` check, ...

So I think the best place to sanitize & validate Phone will be in the model itself.

How can I do that in Laravel 8.x in the most clean way?

I have found many questions like this on internet, but the proposed solutions where either writing a lot of code and bending the framework ad nauseam, or the people didn't grasp the problem at all.

Mabye I should add, that I want this to happen automatically. So anybody who will try to `$phone->save()` or `Phone::create()` phones in wrong format will end up with ValidationException

Edit 2: Provider/Observer - am I looking the right direction?

Edit 3: Events? So in my model, I should do something like:

```
use Notifiable;

protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'validating' => PhoneSanitize::class,
    'saving'     => PhoneValidate::class,
];
```

Edit 4: Or do you think that validating data on model-level is a bad idea? I've read this article:

[Nikola Poša - Self-validating domain model](https://www.nikolaposa.in.rs/blog/2020/08/17/self-validating-domain-model/)

and it seems to me as a good idea. But how can achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried creating a form validation? you can find more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests)

Comment: Yes I did. But I am looking for way how to make validation in model

Answer (score 1):

So for now I solved this with Observer.

Run in shell:

```
php artisan make:observer PhoneObserver --model=Phone
```

Then in *"App/Observers"* you will find *"PhoneObserver"* with some methods. Add method *"saving(Phone $phone)"* where you can sanitize & validate Phone data. *"saving()"* should work both for creating & updating your model

And if you throw (specifically!) ValidationException here with error message, Laravel will redirect you back to your form with that message:

```
/* App/Observers/PhoneObserver.php */

use App\Models\Phone;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class PhoneObserver
{
    public function saving(Phone $phone) 
    {
        /* Do your sanitisation */
        /* Do your validation */
        if (something wrong) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessage(['phone_number' => 'Phone number has wrong format...']);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to "register" this Observer in *"App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php"* in the *"boot()"* method:

```
*/ App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php */

use App\Models\Phone;
use App\Observers\PhoneObserver.php

public function boot()
{
    Phone::observe(PhoneObserver::class);
}
```

I don't know if this is the best place or most clean way to do this, but it works for me now and my Phones are automatically protected from being saved in wrong format.

Hope this helps somebody. I'm new to Laravel & I spent like weeks seeking for the answer. If I find some better way, I'll post it here.

Answer (score -1):

Validating the data on model-level is a bad idea since validation logic is more about form requests.

Being said that, you can use [Eloquent Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to sanitize (or even to validate) your input in the model.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class Phone extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function setPhoneNumberAttribute($value)
    {
        // Do your sanitization
        // ...

        // Do your validation
        Validator::make([
            'phone_number' => $value,
        ], [
            'phone_number' => ['required'], // Define your validation rules
        ])->validate();

        $this->attributes['phone_number'] = $value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If validation fails, the `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException` will be thrown and the user will automatically be redirected or, in the case of an AJAX request, a JSON response will be returned.

Comment: Thank you. But is it really that bad idea? What if I will not only work with that data through web forms but also through API or command-line?

Comment: If you want to use command-line and create your own console commands, you might want to use something like [Command Validator](https://github.com/cerbero90/command-validator) package which validates input in Artisan console commands.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that package. But in that case, I will have to write the validating rules twice. And what about the API access? Is there some API Validator package where I will wrote the same validation rules for the 3rd time? Isn't that violation of the DRY principle?

Comment: API requests are essentially HTTP requests. So, it is perfectly fine to apply the same validation logic both for form and API requests. To avoid repeating validation rules, you may store it in a static property in the model like this: `public static $rules = [ 'phone_number' => ['required'] ];`. Then access it inside the model using `self::$rules` and outside the model using `Phone::$rules`.